# Amplifier Voltage

Tags: voltage, amplifier, dc, gain, biasing

I'm studying for my electronics exam and for this particular problem I have:

Av = –85 (V/V),

Ap 21 (dB) power gain,

Ap = 3.41 (W/W),

L+ = +9 (V),

L- = -6 (V).

Now the next exercise asks that:

If the
input voltage is Vi = A + B sin(ωt) mV, and A is chosen to get the maximum undistorted peak-to-peak
output voltage, find the maximum value of B (in mV) to avoid distortion.

I tried to take it at both extremes ( L-/Av <= Vi <= L+/Av) and solve for Vi taking A = +9 (V) since it gets the maximum peak output voltage (so +9 V) but I'm getting a wrong answer. (The correct answer is 88 mV).

Am I going through this problem correctly? If no what should I know that's missing?

Comment: The A value should be approx -17mV not +9V

Comment: How did you find this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max Vout pp = +9 - (-6) = 15 Vpp = 7.5Vp

Divide by Vgain =85 to get input B.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: On which part?.....

Comment: What do you mean by Vout pp, following why did you divide by Vgain?

Comment: Output may swing between both supplies L+,L- or 15Vpp. Since B is peak voltage times sine then divide by 2.   VOut[pk]/Vgain=Vin [pk]=B

Comment: Very clear and helpful, thank you!